# How to make custom odoo fields with regular expressions

Tags: python, field, odoo

Using odoo 12, I'm trying to make some custom fields adapted to contain specific values with regular expression Eg: 'NN C NNNNNNN' (N:numeric, C:Character).

I'm trying to make these fields contain some default values (like spaces/- ...)  and allow user inputs according to regex.

Just like Key input in picture bellow:

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [inputmask_widget](https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/11.0/inputmask_widget/) module and set the input mask to the field.

```
<field name="serial" widget="mask" data-inputmask="'mask': '99 A 9999999'"/>
```

---

You will notice that the provided link for `inputmask_widget` is for Odoo 11 and I tested it on Odoo 12 and it works.